# Save as PDF creates ghost images of my text behind the text

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, pdf

I'm an Illustrator Novice (I'm more experienced with Photoshop) but I need to create a vector version of our company logo.

The logo looks fine in Illustrator and if I export a png version it looks fine too:

[image]

However, when I save the .ai file as a PDF, I get this weird ghost text behind the other text and the shadows aren't as distinct (I created the shadow by duplicating layers with a small shadow so they would stack up, and I think some of those layers are getting shifted which causes the ghost text as well as the lighter shadow on the main text).

[image]

Here is a link to the original .ai file: http://www.inadaydevelopment.com/StackOverflow/IllustratorGhostText/Logo%202%20Line.ai

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Delete the linked png file on the locked layer then save as PDF.

Your linked file is being shown when you create a PDF.